Converting Excel matrix that contains empty cell to single row
I have a matrix like below image

Is it possible to change it in a way like below?:


I firstly used TOCOL function, but it returned Array instead of strings. As I needed strings, I used breakdown version of Tocol function as below:
=INDEX(range, QUOTIENT(ROW(A1)-1, COLUMNS(range))+1, MOD(ROW(A1)-1, COLUMNS(range))+1)

This has worked better as it will do the samething, but you will need to drag them down.

If those blanks are true blanks, then TOCOL with ignore parameter should work:
=TOCOL(A1:C3,1)


If it is generated array, then filter out blanks:
=FILTER(TOCOL(A1#),TOCOL(A1#)<>"")


